Transformers, AC and DC current
I have a question about transformers and how do they work: I know that the main principles behind a transformer are the mutual induction and Faraday's law; in order to have an emf induced in the secondary coil, I need the magnetic flux to be changing. This is always done using AC current through the primary coil. My question is: since the intensity of the electrical current can vary also in régime of DC (DC means just that the current flows in one direction, but this does not imply that it is also constant), why transformers are used only with AC current? Maybe I know a wrong definition of direct current?


since the intensity of the electrical current can vary also in régime of DC (DC means just that the current flows in one direction, but this does not imply that it is also constant), why transformers are used only with AC current?

In physics (and electrical engineering) we typically don't use that definition of "DC".
Instead we say that every voltage measured over time can be broken up into components as
$$ V(t) = V_{dc} + V_{ac}(t)$$
Where $V_{dc}$ is the "DC component" and is constant over time. $V_{ac}$ is the "AC component", which varies over time but has a time-averaged value of 0.
So when we talk about "DC currents" we do mean constant currents, not varying currents that always have the same direction.

Note that it is common practice in audio circuits that use vacuum tubes for the output transformer (which matches or "gears down" the high impedance of the tube to the low impedance of the loudspeaker) to carry a significant, constant DC current with the AC signal superimposed on it. The transformer completely blocks the DC current from flowing in the secondary while passing the AC component straight to the loudspeaker.
When the output tube first gets fully warm and then begins conducting that DC "idling current" into the transformer, the rate of change of the current in the primary of the transformer is quite slow, and so almost no current is induced in the secondary during the process of turning on the idling current.
